# Mysql get "SUM" of item for specific date choosen with date picker

Tags: php, mysql

I have an app where i can display data from mysql in a table using a date picker.
I need to display also the SUM of this data at the bottom of the table.
but i didn't managed.

I know how to do it for the actual day or previous like that:

```
SELECT SUM(ca_done) FROM ca where jour = CURDATE()
```

But i don't know how to display the total for the period choosen from date picker.

Here is the code i actually use to display data from mysql and the date picker

```
        src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"
        integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   <script type='text/javascript'>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.dateFilter').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
     });
   });
   </script>

   <!-- Search filter -->

   <div id="table-container">
   <form method='post' action=''>
     Start Date <input type='date' class='dateFilter' name='fromDate' value='<?php if(isset($_POST['fromDate'])) echo $_POST['fromDate']; ?>'>

     End Date <input type='date' class='dateFilter' name='endDate' value='<?php if(isset($_POST['endDate'])) echo $_POST['endDate']; ?>'>

     <input class="btn btn-success" type='submit' name='but_search' value='Search'>
   </form>
</div><br>
   <!--  List -->
   <div id="table-container">

     <table class=" table table-striped table-bordered ">
      <thead >
       <tr class="table-primary">
         <th >DATE</th>
         <th >MAG</th>
         <th >CA</th>
         <th >OBJ</th>
         <th >OBJ N-1</th>
         <th >COMMENTAIRES</th>
       </tr>
       </thead>

       <?php
       $shop_query = "SELECT * FROM ca WHERE 1 ";


       // Date filter
       if(isset($_POST['but_search'])){
          $fromDate = $_POST['fromDate'];
          $endDate = $_POST['endDate'];

          if(!empty($fromDate) && !empty($endDate)){
             $shop_query .= " and jour 
                          between '".$fromDate."' and '".$endDate."' ";
          }
        }

        // Sort
        $shop_query .= " ORDER BY jour DESC";
        $shoprecords = mysqli_query($con,$shop_query);

        // Check records found or not
        if(mysqli_num_rows($shoprecords) > 0){
          while($records = mysqli_fetch_assoc($shoprecords)){
            $jour = $records['jour'];
            $shop = $records['shop'];
            $ca_done = $records['ca_done'];
            $objectif = $records['objectif'];
            $objectif_last_year = $records['objectif_last_year'];
            $comments = $records['comments'];

            echo "<td>". $jour ."</td>";
            echo "<td>". $shop ."</td>";
            echo "<td>". $ca_done ."</td>";
            echo "<td>". $objectif ."</td>";
            echo "<td>". $objectif_last_year ."</td>";
            echo "<td>". $comments ."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
          }
        }else{
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td colspan='4'>Aucune données enregistrées.</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
        }
        ?>
      </table>
```

I tried many ways but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: ... also it is really hard to maintain as you are mixing `html javascript mysql php` in 1 file

Comment: It is just an internal tool, not exposed to external network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that right?

```
<table class=" table table-striped table-bordered ">
  <thead ></thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
      $shop_query = "SELECT * FROM ca WHERE 1 ";
      $total_ca_done = 0;  

      // Date filter

       // Sort

       // Check records found or not
       if(mysqli_num_rows($shoprecords) > 0){
         while($records = mysqli_fetch_assoc($shoprecords)){
           //
           $total_ca_done += $records['ca_done'];
           //
           echo "<td>". $ca_done ."</td>";
           echo "</tr>";
         }
       }else{
         //
       }
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
       //
       if ( $total_ca_done > 0 ) {
         echo '<tr><td colspan=2>Total ca_done</td><td>'.$total_ca_done.'</td><td colspan=3></td></tr>';
       }
       ?>    
   </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect it solved my problem , Thank you very much for your help.

https://ibb.co/LPqGX0b

Answer (score 0):

`fromDate` and `endDate` in the form are sent with `yy-mm-dd` format (i.e.: 19-07-18), but MySQL looks for `yyyy-mm-dd` (i.e.: 2019-07-18).

Change `$fromDate` and `$endDate` format like this:

```
$fromDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('y-m-d', $_POST['fromDate'])->format('Y-m-d');
$endDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('y-m-d', $_POST['endDate'])->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Thank you i corrected it but it doesn t solve the problem.

Comment: why does not change dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd" in datepicker params?

Comment: I tried this to get the SUM of ca-done for example but it 's not working.

```("SELECT SUM(ca_done) FROM ca where jour BETWEEN  '".$fromDate."' and '".$endDate."'"); ```

Comment: The date picker is not the problem everything is working fine,  just want to get the total  SUM of for example ```ca_done``` for the date choosen in date picker.

Comment: "It's not working" you said: what's the result? Do you have any errors? What do you expect?

Comment: I didn't have any error it just didn t display the results.